# Specific hover quest

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

i have a question.For exemple you have 3 spans(default color of those is black),on span :hover color changes to red,its ok.But what if i tell you,that at the start,first span has the orange color.Now i want to hover the orange one and it has to became red,and when i unhover it should became black ,as default.And of course on second hover it will be like the other spans(red on hover and black on unhover).Sorry if i didnt explain as well,my english suc*s.Thats what i did http://jsfiddle.net/5oftL12k/5/ kek.
And is it possible to realise this just with css?

```
<span class="class1">blabla</span>
<span class="class2">blabla</span>
<span class="class3">blabla</span>

.class1{color:orange}
span:hover{color:red}
```

Comment: sorry,i updated the link

Comment: I think you'll have to use javascript to get what you want here. no current css has the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with jQuery:

```
$(".class1").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("class1");
})
```

#### 2nd:

```
$(":not('.class1')").mouseover(function(){
  $('.class1').removeClass("class1");
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jmp8rzys/11/

Comment: One,more question,For exemple i just loaded the page and now im hovering the second div,how to make first become black in this moment,i mean as default.I mean doesnt matter where i hover,the first div default color becames black,and hover color becames red.

Comment: ohh,i resolved it like that $(".class1,.class2,.class3").mouseover(function(){
$(".class1").removeClass("class1");
})

Comment: yes, right. some shorter form is:  $("[class^='class']").mouseover(function(){ $(".class1").removeClass("class1"); })

Comment: sir the last question,For exemple i hover on all spans 2-3 times then i stop hovering,how do i return the orange color to first if none of spans are hovered anymore.

Comment: i mean to add class back if my mouse is not anymore on spans

Comment: for that you need to create a new question on SO. I think it's impossible due to contradict to primary specificity of question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('rainbow-hover');
for (var i = spans.length; i--;) {
  let c = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange'];
  spans[i].onmouseover = function() {
    if (!c.length) c = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange'];
    this.style.color = c.shift();
  }
}
```

```html
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span><span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
<span class=rainbow-hover>Hover me</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<span class="class1" id="firstspan">blabla</span>
<span class="class2">blabla</span>
<span class="class3">blabla</span>
```

CSS

```
.class1{
 color: orange;
}

span:hover{
 color: red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var firstSpan = document.getElementById("firstspan");

firstSpan.onmouseover = function() {
 firstSpan.style.color = "red";
};

firstSpan.onmouseout = function() {
 firstSpan.style.color = "black";
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dani1999/5oftL12k/9/